# Geometry homework help: Ratios

Tags: geometry

[image]

Alright so I have done part a, but I don't even understand where to start with part b. I keep ending up in circles where I basically just show that PQ/AB=PQ/AB in some complicated way. I would like to show PQ somehow related to DC since they are parallel and in triangle ADC, but I wouldn't have a number for it.

Answer (score 1):

First note that because of the similar triangles, $\triangle{EBA}\sim\triangle{ABQ}$, we have the equal ratio of sides:

$$\frac{EB}{AB}=\frac{AB}{QB}.$$

Part b) asks for the ratio of $PQ$ to $AB$. The length of segment $PQ$ can be written as the length of segment $EB$ minus the two lengths $EP$ and $QB$, or since $EP=QB$, we can just write $PQ=EB-2QB$. Then,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{PQ}{AB}
&=\frac{EB-EP-QB}{AB}\\
&=\frac{EB-2QB}{AB}\\
&=\frac{EB}{AB}-2\frac{QB}{AB}\\
&=\frac{EB}{AB}-2\left(\frac{AB}{QB}\right)^{-1}\\
&=\frac{EB}{AB}-2\left(\frac{EB}{AB}\right)^{-1}.\\
\end{align}$$

Using the fact that $\frac{EB}{AB}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=\phi$, as well as the fact that the golden ratio satisfies the equation $1+\frac{1}{\phi}=\phi$, we have:

$$\frac{PQ}{AB}=\phi-\frac{2}{\phi}=\phi-2\left(\phi-1\right)=2-\phi=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}.\blacksquare$$